# $.event.trigger not firing in non-DOM object

Tags: event-handling, jquery

```
var test = { }
$(test).on("testEvent", function (){
    console.log("testEvent has fired");
});
$.event.trigger("testEvent");
```

I am trying to using jQuery to do a publish/subscribe mechanism using events. I need to be able to attach events to non-DOM objects and be able to have them all fire from a single global trigger. I expected the code above to work but it did not result in the testEvent firing for the test object.

Note that there will be multiple objects in which an event will be subscribed to. A single $.event.trigger should fire all of those events.

Do note that this code works fine:

```
$('#someID').on("testEvent", function () {
console.log('testEvent has fired from DOM element');
})
$.event.trigger("testEvent");
```

Comment: The reason the event is not firing is because the object is not part of the DOM. When I fire $.event.trigger it is firing the event and bubbling up through the DOM. Seeing as the object is not part of the DOM it does not fire.

What I am really looking for here is to somehow fire events within non-DOM objects globally using jQuery. I'm trying to avoid having to use something like AmplifyJS to accomplish this.

Comment: The only way to trigger the event you posted is with `$(test).trigger("testEvent");`.

Comment: If you do not pass an element to `$.event.trigger` and the event being triggered isn't a global event, it won't trigger an event. See the code block starting on line 3104 of http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js . Since this is an undocumented method, we have to go to the code to see what it does.

Comment: KevinB's comment is right and this seems to be allowed, but doesn't seem totally ideal considering trigger is designed for DOM elements. @crv's solution is probably the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After doing some research it appears as though jQuery 1.7 provides an easy way to introduce a publish/subscribe mechanism. (found [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/)) In order to have a publish/subscribe mechanism the following code can be used:

```
(function ($, window, undefined) {
    var topics = {};

    jQuery.Topic = function (id) {
        var callbacks, method, topic = id && topics[id];
        if (!topic) {
            callbacks = jQuery.Callbacks();
            topic = {
                publish: callbacks.fire,
                subscribe: callbacks.add,
                unsubscribe: callbacks.remove
            };
            if (id) {
                topics[id] = topic;
            }
        }
        return topic;
    };
})
```

In order to subscribe to an event the following is done:

```
$.Topic("message").subscribe(function () {
    console.log("a publish has occurred");
});
```

In order to publish a message the following is done:

```
$.Topic( "message" ).publish(data);
```

"Message" is the event name. The data argument contains any information you want passed to the subscribers.

In order to unsubscribe you must pass the function that was subscribed:

```
$.Topic( "message" ).unsubscribe(funcSubscribedToBefore);
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In modern browsers (If I've [read the source for Underscore.js](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js) right) allow you to bind events to non DOM objects natively.   Otherwise, you'll have to use something like underscore's .bind function.  So it depends upon what browsers you need to support.</strike>

Edit:

Ok, nevermind, I was thinking bind in Underscore.js is the same as with Backbone.  Backbone has it's own events module that does event binding, apparently.

[binding events to dynamic objects in underscore/backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531968/binding-events-to-dynamic-objects-in-underscore-backbone)

Comment: and to add further insult to injury, Backbone.Events now uses the "on/off" syntax, not it's previous bind, etc. syntax. I knew that.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used Ben Alman approach, and it worked great!

```
/* jQuery Tiny Pub/Sub - v0.7 - 10/27/2011
 * http://benalman.com/
 * Copyright (c) 2011 "Cowboy" Ben Alman; Licensed MIT, GPL */

(function ($) {

    var o = $({});

    $.subscribe = function () {
        o.on.apply(o, arguments);
    };

    $.unsubscribe = function () {
        o.off.apply(o, arguments);
    };

    $.publish = function () {
        o.trigger.apply(o, arguments);
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Usage:

```
$.subscribe('eventName', function (event) {
    console.log(event.value);
});

$.publish({ type: 'eventName', value: 'hello world' });
```

See https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/1321768 for more information.